# OCaml tree traversal - how do I traverse a multiway tree

Tags: recursion, tree, ocaml, traversal

How do I traverse a multiway tree with the following type definition from leaves to the top

```
type tree = Branch of float * tree list | Leaf
```

Comment: I would suggest one by one. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Maybe show us a piece of code you tried, and then we can help understanding why it does not work?

Comment: to process the leaves before the node values, first you traverse the list, *then* you  process the node's value.

Answer (score 2):

The same way as you would traverse a binary tree, except that you need to use `List.fold_left` (or another appropriate list iterator) to traverse the subtrees. Below is the general outline,

```
let rec traverse work tree = match tree with 
| Leaf -> ... do the leaf work and add it to `work`...
| Branch (w,trees) -> 
  let r = List.fold_left traverse work trees in
  ... finish the branch work ...
```

Key moments:

1. do not forget `rec` so you can use `traverse` inside `traverse`
2. the `work` parameter holds the work that is done by the already traversed nodes
3. the final result shall be the sum of the work done by all nodes (up to some definition of the sum).