# Traverse a multiway tree

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to traverse a multiway tree, and to map it's values like List.map would.

Here is my attempt

```
type 'a tree = Node of 'a * ('a tree list);;

let tree_map f t = 
  let rec aux acc tr =
    match tr with
    | Node(v, []) -> Node(f v, []) :: acc
    | Node(v, sub) -> let r = List.fold_left aux acc sub in Node(f v, r) :: acc
  in aux [] t
;;

let t = Node (1, [Node (2, [Node (1, [])]); 
                  Node (3, []);
                  Node (1, [Node (5, []); 
                            Node (2, [])])]);;
;;

let res = tree_map (succ) t;;
```

I tried the suggestion from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66006970/ocaml-tree-traversal-how-do-i-traverse-a-multiway-tree) answer. Could not implement it successfully.

My function returns this which is obviously incorrect

```
val res : int tree list =
  [Node (2,
    [Node (2,
      [Node (3, []); Node (6, []); Node (4, []); Node (3, [Node (2, [])])]);
     Node (4, []); Node (3, [Node (2, [])])])]
```

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer that you're referring was about the fold iterator, i.e., when you apply some function to each node of a tree to build some value. The map iterator is a little bit different and is even easier to implement. For each node, you shall return the mapped node.

It is important to keep in mind that the `map` iterator shall preserve the structure of your data, e.g., when you have the leaf node you need to return the mapped leaf node, e.g.,

```
| Node (v, []) -> Node (f v, [])
```

the same is true to the general case, i.e., instead of using the fold iterator, you need to use the `map` iterator, e.g.,

```
| Node(v, sub) -> Node (f v, List.map (aux f) sub)
```

In fact, you don't even need the empty node case as the general case will work fine for all nodes. Which will make you `tree_map` a trivial one-liner :)

And do not forget to remove the `acc` parameter from `aux`, you do not need it.

Comment: Even this: `Node(v, sub) -> Node (f v, List.map (aux f) sub)` seems overcomplicated with the unnecessary `aux`. See @glennsl's answer.

Comment: Sure, but do not forget about the didactic purposes of SO. The challenge is not to give the shortest possible answer with the most beautiful piece of code but to teach how to do this!

Answer (score 6):

Slightly too late to the party, but since I've already done the work and to show you how much the function can be simplified:

```
let rec tree_map f (Node (v, sub)) =
  Node(f v, List.map (tree_map f) sub)
```

Answer (score 3):

A problem I see is that you're just using the result of `List.fold_left` as it stands. But the left fold is going to return a reversed list.

```
# List.fold_left (fun acc n -> (n + 1) :: acc) [] [1;2;3];;
- : int list = [4; 3; 2]
```

A second problem is that you're using `acc` in two places in the same expression:

```
let r = List.fold_left aux acc sub in Node(f v, r) :: acc
```

This is going to duplicate part of the tree. One of the places should be using `[]` instead of `acc`, it seems to me.